# Binary data representation in messages

Tags: ros, binary, serialization, msg, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a documentation on how the information transferred in ros messages is stored in the message's binary data (given that I have the describing msg file) ?

E. g. if I would want to create my own serializer and deserializer for an arbitrary programming language / system, where to find the information on how to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189803/binary-data-representation-in-messages/) by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7555 on 2014-08-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is some documentation. Those should get you started:

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Connection%20Header

http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/MessagesSerializationAndAdaptingTypes

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-08-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2